# Routing Error uninitialized constant GradesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I decided to start a Ruby on Rails project without scaffolding because I actually wanted to learn in the process. I have searched this site but cannot seem to find the answer to my question so I will ask here. I started a Rails project where the user enters their grades. Unfortunately, on the new grade page when the user hits Create Grade I get the error in the subject line. Here is my code for the form that I use in the new page under the grade controller.

```
<%= form_with(model: grade, local: true) do |f| %>
<% if grade.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(grade.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this grade 
from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% grade.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :assignment %>
<%= f.text_field :assignment %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :score %>
<%= f.text_field :score %>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

This is my routes page:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :grades
root 'grade#index'
get 'grade/index'
get 'grade/show'
get 'grade/new'
get 'grade/edit'
get 'grade/create'
get 'grade/update'
get 'grade/destroy'
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

If more code is needed to answer the question please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the title of your question, Rails is looking for a file called app/controllers/grades_controller.rb file that defines the GradesController class.

Create the following file, and you should get to the next step

```
# app/controllers/grades_controller.rb
class GradesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @grade = Grade.new
  end

  def create
    # logic for persisting the grade object goes here
  end

  # other controller methods, here
end
```

In the form for a new grade, use the instance variable (the one with the @ symbol) you defined in the GradesController#new method:

```
<%= form_with(model: @grade, local: true) do |f| %>
```

In your routes, this is all you should need:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :grades
  root 'grades#index' # not 'grade#index'
end
```

Comment: `root 'grades#index'`

Comment: Unfortunately, with those changes I now get this error when I type in localhost:3000: Routing Error
uninitialized constant GradeController. I included the s in GradesController but the error lists the singular.

Comment: Routing Error
uninitialized constant GradeController
Rails.root: C:/Sites/scores

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes
Routes match in priority from top to bottom

Helper HTTP Verb Path Controller#Action
Path / Url  
Path Match
grades_path GET /grades(.:format) 
grades#index

POST /grades(.:format) 
grades#create

new_grade_path GET /grades/new(.:format) 
grades#new

edit_grade_path GET /grades/:id/edit(.:format) 
grades#edit

grade_path GET /grades/:id(.:format) 
grades#show

PATCH /grades/:id(.:format) 
grades#update

PUT /grades/:id(.:format)

Comment: Appoligize for the sloppiness. That is as much as it would let me paste.

Comment: I feel like there is something we aren't seeing. Any chance you could push your code to GitHub or GitLab and give us a link?

Comment: I'm having difficulty with pushing it to Github also. I will post a separate question regarding that and then return to this thread. However, I noticed the comment from max just now. I changed grade#index to grades#index and got a new error. I will post that in the next comment.

Comment: ActionController::UnknownFormat in GradesController#index
GradesController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.
Extracted source (around

Comment: Ah, yes! Progress! The keywords here are "missing template." Based on the error message, you need to define a view template for the index page for grades.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are plural, check the name of the controller file to ensure it's plural then check the controller class name change both from GradeController to GradesController.